# Borel measurable functions equal almost everywhere

Tags: probability, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, borel-measures

If $(\Omega,F,\mu)$ is the completion of a measure space $(\Omega,F_{0},\mu)$ and $f$ is a Borel measurable function on $(\Omega,F)$, then show that there exists a Borel measurable function g on $(\Omega,F_{0})$ such that $f=g$ except on a subset of a set in $F_{0}$ of measure 0.

The author proposes to start with indicator functions, but I'm not even sure how to start tackling this problem.

Answer (score 0):

No topology is mentioned, so I will assume that the word "Borel" is not there.

If $X\in F$, then $X=A\cup E$, with $A\in F_0$ and $\mu(E)=0$. So $1_X=1_A$ with the possible exception of a subset of $E$; by definition, $E\subset E_0$ for some nullset $E_0\in F_0$, so $1_X=1_A$ outside of $E_0$. That is, $1_X=1_A$ almost everywhere in $F_0$ and $1_A$ is measurable in $F_0$. Using this idea, we get that for any simple $f$ measurable on $F$, there exists a simple function $g$ measurable on $F_0$ and $f=g$ a.e.

Now for any function $f$ measurable on $F$, there exists a sequence of simple functions $f_n$ with $f_n\to f$ pointwise. Let $g_n$ be simple, measurable on $F_0$, with $f_n=g_n$ up to a nullset $E_n\in F_0$. Put $E=\bigcup_nE_n\in F_0$, still a nullset. Define $g=f\,1_{E^c}$. As $g=\lim_ng_n\,1_{E^c}$, it is a limit of functions which are measurable in $F_0$, so it is also measurable in $F_0$. And $g=f$ outside of $E$.

Comment: By Borel measurable i mean that the function is real valued with the usual topology generated by the absolute value norm.

Comment: Fair enough. It's just not the common usage of the term. Usually "measurable" alone is taken to mean "preimages of open sets are measurable" which is what you have. "Borel measurable" is commonly used to mean that you have a topological space, and that the function is measurable with respect to the Borel $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the line: "by definition, $E \subset E_0$ for some nullset $E_0 \subset F_0$ (this I understood) so $1_X = 1_A$ **out of $F$**"? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Don't know what I tried to write back then. I have edited to try and clarify.